# Which PID listens on a given mach port

Tags: macos, mach

My application receives mach IPC messages and return answers for the callers. I have mach caller `port(msgh_remote_port)` and I want to know `PID` of the caller.
Can I find on OSX by the mach port a `PID` which listen for specific mach port?

Answer (score 3):

The mach port is not directly associated with a process, but instead with a task. The task is then associated with the bsd process structure. To query the ports of a task you can use the mach_port_names function. To get all the open mach ports iterate over all the tasks and use the above mentioned function.

A different approach is to use the procfs filesystem. The procfs filesystem is implemented on top of the fuse filesystem and needs to be manually installed on a system. It is a open source solution. Once the procfs filesystem is installed you can query the ports of a task by accessing the file /proc/proc-id/task/ports. Have a look at [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200816070829/https://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter11/procfs/).

Answer (score 0):

Three ways you can do this without a kext:

- launchctl print system (or another domain)
- lsmp -a (no port names, just ids)
- procexp all ports | grep the_service_name_you_want

  (procexp is an add on tool from http://NewOSXBook.com/tools/procexp.html)